# How to use jquery-uix-multiselect with Active Admin and Bower?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I tried to use jquery-uix-multiselect in my Rails-App with ActiveAdmin.

my bower.json looks like this:

```
{
  "lib": {
    "name": "bower-rails generated lib assets",
    "dependencies": {
    }
  },
  "vendor": {
    "name": "bower-rails generated vendor assets",
    "dependencies": {
      "jquery-uix-multiselect": "^1.0.0",
      "jquery-ui": "latest"
    }
  }
}
```

after I loaded this bower packages with "rake bower:install" I added this lines to "app/assets/active_admin.js":

```
//= require jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min
//= require jquery-uix-multiselect/js/jquery.uix.multiselect.min

$('select[multiple="multiple"]').multiselect();
```

in my "app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss"  I added this:

```
@import "jquery-uix-multiselect/css/jquery.uix.multiselect"
```

my html looks like this:
[image]

where is my mistake?